# How do I reference one Eclipse project from another?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two Java projects in Eclipse as follows:

1. Client (a Swing application)
2. Contracts (something like a class library in the .NET world)

I would like my client to reference the Contracts project. Here is what I have done.

I have a class in my client project like so:

```
package practice.bookyard.client;

public interface IAuthenticationManager {
    OperationResult<String> AuthenticateUser(String userName, 
                                    String password);
}
```

And in the Contracts project, another class like so:

```
package practice.bookyard.contracts;

public class OperationResult<T> {
    protected final boolean successful;
    protected final String errorMessage;
    protected final T data;

    public OperationResult(boolean successful, String errorMessage, T data)  {
        this.successful = successful;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean getSuccessful() { 
        return this.successful;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() { 
        return this.errorMessage;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

To reference the **Contracts** project from the client, I right-clicked on the client project properties, and selected the checkbox next to the contracts project name in the list of **Project References**.

However, when I try to use the `OperationResult<T>` class in my client project, it doesn't recognize it at all.

So, I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong in setting the references?
2. How do I build a project that has just classes in it with no `main` function? Like my contracts project?

I am using Eclipse for Java EE, Mars 2.

[image]

Comment: Check the build path.

Comment: @Kayaman: What to check it for? Could you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: For the missing reference to the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to add the other project to the *Java Build Path*.

Got to the project properties -> Java Build Path and in  the tab 'Projects' add the other project.

Comment: 8 mins before I can mark your answer as the right one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out just a few seconds ago by trial and error. Apparently, you must add the project you want to reference to the list of "Projects that are required in the build path before you build this project."

[image]

It works now.